# Vectors calculation based on speed and angles

Tags: vector, coordinates, angle

I am having a tough time applying vector knowledge to a real situation: I am working on implementing a near collision detection algorithm for ships (not predictor) based on [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273123985_Assessment_of_ship_collision_estimation_methods_using_AIS_data) paper. The data I have is *location* (x,y), *course* (angle from north), and *speed* for each ship (let's say only ship A and B).

Three of the components I need are: relative velocity between the ships, unit vector parallel to ship course, unit vector perpendicular to relative velocity (the overall formulas can be seen in chapter 4). The first formula is given in the paper, while the next 2 I got from a math book:

```
1) relative velocity V(BA) = C(B) - C(A) (all vectors; within brackets -> subscript)
```

I'm assuming the C's mean the course (which is an angle). From my understanding,  relative velocity is measured in distance over time while a vector has a magnitude (speed?) and orientation (course?).

```
2) unit vector = vector / magnitude
3) perpendicular vector = any vector <=> dot product = 0
```

Therefore my question is: how do I use the data I have (i.e. speed, course, location) to calculate these equations?

Regarding vectors, the only thing that comes to mind to calculate a vector is using two points (so 2 x,y pairs), which however seems odd in this case.

Comment: Not really a Python problem as much as it is pure math?

Comment: Velocity is a vector, it has magnitude and direction. And no, it is probably not a angel but vector subtraction..

Comment: You seem to be having trouble converting Polar vectors (magnitude, angle orientation) to Cartesian (horizontal magnitude, vertical magnitude). You can [readily switch between the two](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolarCoordinates.html).

Comment: If a ship travels 4 meters east and 3 meters north, and another ship travels 1 meters south and 3 meters west. I define my system as east along the x axis and north along the y axis. The first ships velocity is (4, 3) and the other ship (-1, -3). The relative vector is then (4, 3) - (-1, -3) = [(4-(-1)), (3-(-3))] = (5, 6).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have position in coordinates `x` (horizontal, positive when West to East) and `y` (vertical, positive when South to North), a speed `s` and a course `c` (angle in relation to North, clockwise) for each ship.

You can get the Cartesian components of the velocity, v<sub>x</sub> and v<sub>y</sub>, by using:

> v<sub>y</sub> = `s`cos(`c`)
>
> v<sub>x</sub> = `s`sin(`c`)

And then you can [add or subtract the vectors term-wise](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/vectors/Lesson-1/Vector-Addition) at will.

Comment: So in my case, I would do Vy + Vx for each ship to obtain the vectors CB and CA; then for relative velocity, I just do CB-CA, correct? I have the feeling I am missing a sqrt

Comment: Not really, it seems you are confused to [what a vector is](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/vectors/Lesson-1/Vectors-and-Direction). As each vector has two components, C<sub>A</sub>=(v<sub>x,A</sub>, v<sub>y,A</sub>) and C<sub>B</sub>=(v<sub>x,B</sub>, v<sub>y,B</sub>). This would make V<sub>BA</sub>=(v<sub>x,B</sub>-v<sub>x,A</sub>, v<sub>y,B</sub>-v<sub>y,A</sub>).

Comment: So is speed a vector? or the magnitude of a vector? Wiki states speed is the magnitude, so speed would be `s = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)`, where x and y (I presume) would be the Cartesian components. Is this correct? What confuses me is that both velocity(a vector?) and speed(scalar?) are measured in distance/time. V<sub>y</sub> calculation above would be distance^2/time(?!)

Comment: No, speed is a scalar, it's the magnitude of velocity, which is a vector. A vector in 2D can be described by both it's components in each axis (vx and vy) or by its magnitude and course. Imagine a right triangle, the hypotenuse's length is the speed and each cathetus is a componente of the vector in the x and y direction. All of those quantities are measured in the same unit, distance/time in this case, and because of trigonometry rules you can describe the vector by any combination of two of those or one of those and an angle, or two angles. See Simon's comment on your original question.